# How to catch tcp client request message in wso2 esb proxy service

Tags: tcp, wso2, wso2-esb

Im new comer to Wso2 esb. Now I'm working with tcp protocol and proxy service. I have some question. I send some message to the proxy service through tcp protocol. I need get this message to the property mediator in the proxy service. But my way not catch that value in the property mediator.
Here is my proxy service

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="TCPProxyService" startOnLoad="true" transports="tcp" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property description="" expression="get-property('message')" name="MessageValue" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log description="" level="custom">
                <property name="property_name" value="============================="/>
                <property expression="get-property('MessageValue')" name="inputValue"/>
            </log>
            <sequence key="in-sequence"/>
            <log/>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.tcp.responseClient">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.tcp.inputType">string</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.tcp.recordDelimiter">|</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.tcp.contentType">text/plain</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.tcp.port">6789</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.tcp.recordDelimiterType">character</parameter>
</proxy>
```

Here is my Java client for send tcp request

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPClient {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        String delimiter = "|";
        int modifiedSentence;
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new 
           DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String message = "Pietoo,Klaas,also" + delimiter;
        outToServer.writeBytes(message);
        outToServer.flush();
        while ((modifiedSentence = inFromServer.read()) > -1){
           System.out.print((char)modifiedSentence);
        }
        clientSocket.close();
        }
}
```

I tried to add below property mediator with get-property expression. What is the wrong with this.

> property description="" expression="get-property('message')" name="MessageValue" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

Comment: I think message in stream should be wrapped with envelope, otherwise how you will identify separate messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try a `<log level="full"/>` in your proxy def, send it a message with your java client and have a look to wso2-esb-service.log : you should see a soap message like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">your|data</text>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

You can get the text value with :

```
<property xmlns:tp="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload" name="MessageValue" expression="$body/tp:text"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Jean-Michel!.Firstly  I only added $body to expression. Then inputValue property show some xml value like inputValue = , Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">Pietoo,Klaas,also,Nuwan</text></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> this. Why this. can I catch only message value as "Pietoo,Klaas,also,Nuwan" .

Comment: When I add your expression like expression="$body/tp:text" its show error as ERROR - SynapseXPath Evaluation of the XPath expression $body/tp:text resulted in an error

Comment: I can't see the full xml in your first comment... What can you see exactly with just <log level="full"/> ?

Comment: Inside the ESB, every message will be encapsulated in a SOAP Envelope / body, whatever his mime type

Comment: Cannot resolve namespace prefix 'tp' : did you specify this namespace inside property mediator with xmlns:tp="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload" ?

Comment: I didn't know about this "Inside the ESB, every message will be encapsulated in a SOAP Envelope / body" thing. Thank you. Because this my first problem is ok. And when I use expression="$body/tp:text" its show error as Cannot resolve namespace prefix 'tp'. what is this tp?. How to fixed this error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147227/discussion-between-dev4world-and-jean-michel).

Comment: So why We need to add expression="$body/tp:text" like this. It's already work for expression="$body. Wht's wrong with me

Comment: dou you have any idea about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132859/how-to-send-response-as-string-using-class-mediator-in-wso2-esb problem. Kindly help me. Thank you