# Convert text value to the xml in wso2 esb tool

Tags: xml, tcp, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to work with wso2 esb tool and tcp request. I send text request from my client to the proxy service through tcp protocol. I catch that text value from property mediator according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653915/how-to-catch-tcp-client-request-message-in-wso2-esb-proxy-service). Here is my client

```
class TCPClient {
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    String delimiter = "|";
    int modifiedSentence;
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6790);
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    //String message2 = "WZ2OCS2:1:21:1:1:@1479122000#"+ delimiter;
    String message2 = "Nuwan,34,Sama;Kuma,23,Sanga;Ara,78,siva"+ delimiter;
    outToServer.writeBytes(message2);
    outToServer.flush();
    while ((modifiedSentence = inFromServer.read()) > -1){
        System.out.print((char)modifiedSentence);
    }
    clientSocket.close();
}
```

}

Now I need to convert this

> "Nuwan,34,Sama;Kuma,23,Sanga;Ara,78,siva"

value to the json or xml. I tried to use Data **Mapper mediator** and **Smooks mediator** . But I couldnt set that text request to any above two mediators. When I go to to try with foreach mediator I faced like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718783/how-to-add-expression-on-wso2-esb-foreach-mediator-when-request-is-text) problem. I tried lot of way as I can> How can I solve this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to this sample :

```
<property name="TEXT" value="Nuwan,34,Sama;Kuma,23,Sanga;Ara,78,siva"/>
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
    var resultXML = new XML(<sample></sample>)
    var values=mc.getProperty("TEXT").split(',');
    for each(var value in values) {
        resultXML.appendChild(<value>{value}</value>);
    }               
    mc.setPayloadXML(resultXML);
]]></script>
```

It will return this payload :

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Header/>
   <S:Body>
      <sample>
         <value>Nuwan</value>
         <value>34</value>
         <value>Sama;Kuma</value>
         <value>23</value>
         <value>Sanga;Ara</value>
         <value>78</value>
         <value>siva</value>
      </sample>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Adapt this sample to your need.

Comment: Thank you Jean-Michel. I search this since two days. You saved me.