# how to send response as String using class mediator in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2-esb

In my project I created some proxy.There **transport type is tcp**. 
My response is

```
{
 "BillingSystem": {
   "request_id": "20114140080000011479122000",
   "request_timestamp": "12102012121200",
   "response_timestamp": "12102012121300",
   "action": "AddSubscription",
   "username": "Cellcard ",
   "result_code": "0",
   "result_desc": "Success"
 }
}
```

I catch this response using class mediator and create  WZ2OCS2:1:14:14008:1:@1479122000# using that response. I need to send this string to **tcp client**. I set this String in the class meditor

```
context.setProperty("responseClientValue", responseClientValue);
```

After set this value in class mediator I used payload factory mediator and after that property mediator.

```
<payloadFactory description="" media-type="xml">
      <format>
          <name xmlns="">$1</name>
      </format>
      <args>
          <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('responseClientValue')"/>
      </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

property mediator

```
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/text"/>
```

When I run project Its show xml code

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><name>WZ2OCS2:1:14:14008:1:@1479122000#</name></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>?
```

Here is my proxy service

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="SurepayBillingErrorHandlingProxy" startOnLoad="true" transports="tcp" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <class description="" name="esb.cellcard.billing.SurepayMediator"/>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="SurpayBillingEP"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <class name="esb.cellcard.billing.ResponseRequestId"/>
            <payloadFactory description="" media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <name xmlns="">$1</name>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('responseClientValue')"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/text"/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.tcp.responseClient">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.tcp.inputType">string</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.tcp.recordDelimiter">?</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.tcp.contentType">text/plain</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.tcp.port">6050</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.tcp.recordDelimiterType">character</parameter>
</proxy>
```

How can I get only string value. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your payloadFactory like this :

```
<payloadFactory>
    <format>
        <text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">$1</text>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:responseClientValue"/>
</payloadFactory>
```

Change property messageType like this :

```
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/plain"/>
```

(see axis2.xml, by default, the PlainTextFormatter class is associated with text/plain : `<messageFormatter contentType="text/plain" class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextFormatter"/>`)

Comment: @Jean-Mechil. When I send request through tcp client I add delimiter to the request. ex -: request+"?" .But when come to response delimiter attached with response.As WZ2OCS2?. How can I remove that delimiter from response.Thank you